# How to transform STDEV of a numerical value to logarithmic value?

Tags: data-transformation, standard-deviation, logarithm

I have the following question:

- I have the average and STDEV values of variable. To transform this to Log10 scale, I directly apply the logarithm to the average. Can I do the same with the STDEV?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your data exactly and what do you hope to accomplish? The transformation is of course possible but it's not clear that this achieves anything useful.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you want to use the original standard deviation to calculate what the standard deviation of the logarithms would have been if you had calculated it before you erased the data?

Comment: In general, it is not possible to estimate mean or sd of $\log(x)$ merely from knowing $mean(x)$ and $sd(x)$. Even your assumption that you can take the logarithm of the mean does not hold, as the simple counterexample in the comments to Peter Flom' answer demonstrates. There are two approaches, however, that you can try: 1) If the error is small with respect to the value, i.e. $\sigma <\!\!< \mu$, you can try Gauss' law of error propagation. 2) As you seem to assume that x is normally distributed, use a Monte Carlo simulation to compute a confidence interval for $\log(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try it and see?

Of course, all your data have to be positive, or log is troublesome. So, e.g. (R code, anything after a # is a comment)

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000, 100, 2)
xlog <- log10(x)

mean(x) #99.94
mean(xlog) #1.99 (which is, indeed, log10 of 99.94)

sd(x) #1.99
sd(xlog) #0.087
log10(2) #0.30
```

So, it seems like the answer is "no".

**EDIT (As the question is closed, this seems to be the only way to provide an answer, feel free to edit the edit if this is undue):** On the other hand, this is an example where Gauss' law of error propagation works quite well and yields a usable correction factor. For a function of only one variable, we have

$$\sigma(f(x)) \approx \left| \sigma(x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\mu_x) \right|$$
which is $\sigma_x / \mu_x$ for $f(x)=\ln(x)$. In Peter Flom's simulation experiment, this works close to perfectly:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000, 100, 2)
xlog <- log(x)

sd(xlog)       # 0.01996927
sd(x) / mean(x) # 0.01995737
```

Comment: The simulation isn't a reasonable test at all, because the original CV is so small that both the data and their logarithms essentially have Normal distributions.  Change the mean from 100 to, say, 1; exponentiate `x` to ensure it's positive; and try again ;-).

Comment: @whuber That's a good point: The approximation typically only makes sense for small coefficients of variation, i.e. if $\sigma<< \mu$. Otherwise, the approximation of the mean is grossly inaccurate, e.g. in whuber's example: `x <- exp(rnorm(1000, 1, x)); xlog <- log(x); log(mean(x)) # 3.13; mean(xlog) # 0.98`

Comment: @peter-flom Please excuse my addition of the result of the approximation by Gauss' law. I thought this is a well formulated question that requires some suggestions what could be tried, but the question was closed. Plese feel free to remove my edit, if you consider it undue. I will try to provide some suggestions as comments to the question.

Comment: @cdalitz Given that the question is closed, I think you did what you could do.